# Is a function necessarily measurable, given that all of its level sets are measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the set $$T_{\alpha} \equiv \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) = \alpha\}$$ is measurable $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Is $f$ measurable?

Here's the proof I've sketched, but I'd like to know whether I'm on the right way or not.

Since $T_\alpha$ is measurable $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $$T^{+}_{\beta} \equiv \mathbb{R}/\bigcup_{\alpha = \beta}^{+\infty}T_{\alpha} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) < \beta\}$$ is also measurable $\forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Function $f$ does not have to be measurable. The *uncountable* union mentioned in your proof does not have to be measurable.

Comment: The question does not match the title.

Comment: @Mariella Rinaldi A more accurate way to summarize the question in words would "Is a function necessarily measurable, given that all of its level sets are measurable?"

Comment: @ErickWong, I've made the change you suggested, thank you. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'd like to know whether I'm on the right way or not.

Unfortunately not. Others have already provided counterexamples, so you now know that your conjecture is false, and that your proof must therefore contain a wrong step. In particular, your proof states that
$$\bigcup_{\alpha = \beta}^{+\infty}T_{\alpha}$$
is measurable since each $T_\alpha$ is such, but this reasoning step is unsound.

Indeed, the above argument only holds for *countable unions*, and the union above is not countable: it involves a set for every real $\geq \beta$.

If any union (with no size bounds) of measurable sets were measurable, then all sets would be measurable, provided singletons are. This follows by the trivial union
$$A = \bigcup_{a\in A} \{a\}$$

Comment: Excellent answer. I always find it annoying when people just put a one line counter-example, which doesn't really help the answerer. This is exactly the sort of answer that I'd like to get if I were to have answered this question -- kudos. Shame I can only give you +1 not +$r$ for a large (integer?) $r$! (Not factorial: exclamation mark!)

Answer (score 11):

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set. Set $f(x) = x$ for $x \in A$ and $f(x) = e^x+2$ otherwise. Then $f$ satisfies your assumptions as it is one-to-one. But $f^{-1}([0,1])$ is non-measurable.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question as stated is no.

As a counterexample, take $g(x)$ to be the characteristic function of any non-measurable set $A$.  Then, define $f(x) = g(x) + x$. Note that any level set has at most two elements and is thus of measure $0$.